# What is a function that could separate these numbers into 2 different sets?

Tags: functions, algorithms

I am trying to write a function, that given these pairs:
(10, 20), (1, 31), (2, 32), (13, 23), (4, 14), (5, 25), (16, 26), (7, 17), (8, 28), (19, 29) if I input one number of the pair the answer = 1 (i.e. half are in one set), and if I put in the other number, the answer = 0 (i.e. half are in another set). So for example, 10 = 0 and 20 = 1 OR vice versa. But both numbers of the pair cannot both equal the same number.

I'm having a lot of trouble finding a distinguishing characteristic. I've tried things like:

0 if > 10 or < 20, 1 otherwise

0 if mod 3 is odd, 1 if mod 3 is even

etc. and more. But I am really struggling. Can anyone help?

Comment: Plot them. Maybe a straight line will do.

Comment: Well, the pairs are not really meant to be ordered pairs in the sense of plotted points. Just my way of organizing them to try to make this more coherent. I did try visualizing it out though, but there's no line that separates them so every "pair" has a number on each side. :(

Comment: Plot the values on a one-dimensional number line. Color the first number of each pair red and the second number of each pair blue. Do you see anything helpful?

Answer (score 1):

> $(\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{0}, 20), \,(1, 31), \,(2, 32), \,(\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{3}, 23), \,(4, 14), \,(5, 25), \,(\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{6}, 26), \,(7, 17), \,(8, 28), \,(\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{9}, 29)$

That's a small enough set that one could define a function $\,f\,$ by cases for each value. But, assuming the question is looking for some sort of a closed form solution, the following will return $\,0\,$ for the first number in each pair, and non-$0\,$ otherwise:

$$
f(n) = \big(n \bmod 10 \big) + 10 \cdot \bigg(1 - \Big( \big((n \bmod 10) \bmod 3\big)^2 \bmod 3 \Big) \bigg) - n
$$

This is based on the observation that the tens digit of the first number in each pair is $\,\color{red}{1}\,$ *iff* the units digit $\,n \bmod 10\,$ is a multiple of $\,3\,$ i.e. $\,\color{blue}{0},\color{blue}{3},\color{blue}{6},\color{blue}{9}\,$.